# using rails helpers in angularjs templates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I'm working on a Rails 3.2 + AngularJS app and have put all my angularJS code under a rails route called 'api_path' (EG: /api#)

When setting up a link to CRUD functions such as 'show' in my AngularJS template I've been doing something like the following;

```
<td><a href="/api#/costings/{{costing.id}}">Show</td>
```

My AngularJS template is in the asset pipeline and named show.html.erb. I know it's compiling the erb correctly as I can do <%= 2 + 2 %> and that works.

I have a method in my application_helper.rb file like so;

```
  def link_to_api(title, path)
    link_to title, api_path + "#" + path
  end
```

If I try and use this in my AngularJS template I get the error:

```
NoMethodError at /costings/index.html.erb
=========================================

> undefined method `link_to_api' for #<#<Class:0x007f4e8f550340>:0x007f4e9391ab20>
  (in app/assets/templates/costings/index.html.erb)

app/assets/templates/costings/index.html.erb, line 8
```

Here is what I tried in the template

```
<td><%= link_to_api("Show", "costings/{{costing.id}}") %></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't think it is a good idea to use a helper within AngularJS.
2. The template in `assets/*` can't share the `applicationHelper` scope, so it can't do this.
3. If you have to, try to use an erb in `views/*` and it should work.

Comment: Fair point. So is there a better way of setting my paths than '<td><a href="/api#/costings/{{costing.id}}">Show</td>'?

Comment: api_path as angular-constants ,then try ui-router. And put the title and path in scope....im not sure about ur requirements.